# making an exe low priority

Tags: c++, executable

How do I run a `.exe` as low priority? I know I can go to task manager, and change the priority setting there manually, but is there a way that I can launch the `.exe` from a `.bat` file with a command to make the .exe run at a given priority (in this case low)? The .exe is a program that I've written in C++; can I set the priority in C++ code?

I am running windows xp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a batch file, you can use the `start` command:

```
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/AFFINITY <hex affinity>] [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program]
      [parameters]

[ . . . ]

    LOW         Start application in the IDLE priority class
    NORMAL      Start application in the NORMAL priority class
    HIGH        Start application in the HIGH priority class
    REALTIME    Start application in the REALTIME priority class
    ABOVENORMAL Start application in the ABOVENORMAL priority class
    BELOWNORMAL Start application in the BELOWNORMAL priority class
```

Answer (score 4):

To voluntarily drop your process priority, use [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(VS.85).aspx). Also see the full [discussion of process and thread priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685100(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the following links for more information about START command that posted by **bobbymcr**:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/875182

Or you can run **cmd.exe** then type: **START /?**

It will display all information about **START** command.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function in top of your c++ code

BOOL WINAPI SetPriorityClass(*In*  HANDLE hProcess,*In*  DWORD dwPriorityClass);

hProcess is the handler of your process which can get by GetCurrentProcess().

for low priority sets dwPriorityClass = REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS